# simple arduino code without using avr headers in avr-libc

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller

I have this simple code

That I am trying to compile for arduino microcontroller and without using avr headers. I just defined all macros in my source program file

but my gcc-avr says

```
led.c:15:8: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   DDRB |= 0B100000; // PORTB5 1010
        ^
```

Now I can expect this error on some cpu that io area is not virtual memory space of this process but I am running my code on mocrocontroller that must have execution bit. how to get rid of this message and compile it and able to run on arduino

But the gcc-avr throws error that

```
#define F_CPU 16000000
#define BLINK_DELAY_MS 5000

#include <util/delay.h>

#define __SFR_OFFSET 0x20
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) ((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
#define DDRB    _SFR_IO8(0x04)
#define PORTB   _SFR_IO8(0x05)
int main (void)
{
  // Arduino digital pin 13 (pin 5 of PORTB) for output
  DDRB |= 0B100000; // PORTB5 1010
  
  while(1) {
    // turn LED on
    PORTB |= 0B100000; // PORTB5
   // _delay_ms(BLINK_DELAY_MS);
   int x=0;
   
    while(x<25)
    {
        x++;
    }
    x=0;
    // turn LED off
    PORTB &= ~ 0B100000; // PORTB5
    //hello
    while(x<25)
    {
        x++;
    }
    //_delay_ms(BLINK_DELAY_MS);
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to know gcc-avr flag or switch to able to compile it so gcc not gonna assume I plan to run it on cpu on computer rather run on microcontroller

Comment: Look into the header files of avr-libc and see how they do it. You are missing at least some de-referencing operator in your assignment, as `DDRB` is a pointer.

Comment: But hey, why in the first place don't you want to use the header files?

Comment: Eventhough SO is not a forum, and therefore this is not the place for discussions, header files are a just declarations, for example for implementations in other modules or libraries. If you write them yourself to link to existing libraries, you have gained little.

Comment: To focus on **my task** I don't want to re-invent the wheel. And I don't want others to get drowned in lots of code irrelevant to the application, or uncommon solutions. ;-) But as an exercise for a beginner, it seems OK to avoid other's code. How comes that you trust the compiler and use a high-level language like C? Won't you rather use assembler? I did in my first years.

Comment: Concerning the pointer issue: Read the code of avr-libc, learn, and do **not** program by accident. "Trying" is copying blindly... and you said you don't want that. Write your code based on solid understanding. Feel free to [edit] your question, showing what you understood, what you don't, and refine the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are the macros, you are defining the register as an integer, not as an address to an integer.

`DDRB` expands to `0x04 + 0x20` so you end up with code like `(0x04 + 0x20) |= 0B100000;`. You should be able to fix this with a cast and then de-reference:

```
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) ( *(volatile uint8_t*) ((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET) )
```

For details see [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Please also note that macros starting with double underscore `__` are reserved for the compiler, so we should never use that or we might end up with naming collisions.